# Dart WebGL not rendering

Tags: opengl-es, dart, webgl, dart-html

I'm trying to write something with WebGL and Dart but I'm having problems. This is my source code.

This is my main file:

```dart
library warmup;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:web_gl' as WebGL;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';

part 'graphics.dart';

WebGL.RenderingContext gl;
CanvasElement canvas;

QuadRenderer renderer;

Random random = new Random();

void main() {
  querySelector("#paragraf").setInnerHtml("HELLO!");
  canvas = querySelector("#game_canvas");
  new Game().start();
}

class Game {

  Texture test = new Texture("tex/test.png");

  void start() {
    gl = canvas.getContext3d();
    if (gl == null) {
      print("No WebGL!");
    }
    Texture.loadAll();

    renderer = new QuadRenderer();
    renderer.projMatrix = makeOrthographicMatrix(0, canvas.width, 0, canvas.height, -1, 1);

    gl.disable(WebGL.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(WebGL.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(WebGL.SRC_ALPHA, WebGL.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(_update);
  }

  int now, last = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  double unprocessedFrames;

  void _update(double time) {

    now = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    unprocessedFrames = (now - last) * 60 / 1000;
    while (unprocessedFrames > 1.0) {

      tick();
      unprocessedFrames--;
    }

    renderGame();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(_update);
  }

  void tick() {

  }

  void renderGame() {

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clear(WebGL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.bindTexture(test);
    renderer.renderQuad(new Vector2(canvas.width / 2.0, canvas.height / 2.0), 128, 128, 0, 0, false);
  }
}
```

This is my graphics.dart file:

```dart
part of warmup;

class Texture {
  static List<Texture> _pending = new List<Texture>();

  String url;
  int width, height;
  WebGL.Texture data;
  bool loaded = false;

  Texture(this.url) {
    if (gl == null) {
      _pending.add(this);
    }
    else {
      load();
    }
  }

  static void loadAll() {
    _pending.forEach((e) => e.load());
    _pending.clear();
  }

  void load() {
    ImageElement img = new ImageElement();
    data = gl.createTexture();
    img.onLoad.listen((e) {
      gl.bindTexture(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D, data);
      gl.texImage2DImage(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, WebGL.RGBA, WebGL.RGBA, WebGL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
      gl.texParameteri(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D, WebGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, WebGL.NEAREST);
      gl.texParameteri(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D, WebGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, WebGL.NEAREST);
      width = img.width;
      height = img.height;
      loaded = true;
    });
    img.src = url;
  }
}

class Vertex {

  Vector2 pos;
  Vector4 color;
  Vector2 texCoord;

  static int elementBytes = 8;

  static int posElementCount = 2;
  static int colorElementCount = 4;
  static int textureElementCount = 2;

  static int posBytesCount = posElementCount * elementBytes;
  static int colorByteCount = colorElementCount * elementBytes;
  static int textureByteCount = textureElementCount * elementBytes;

  static int posByteOffset = 0;
  static int colorByteOffset = posByteOffset + posBytesCount;
  static int textureByteOffset = colorByteOffset + colorByteCount;

  static int elementCount = posElementCount + 
        colorElementCount + textureElementCount;  

  static int stride = posBytesCount + colorByteCount + 
        textureByteCount;

  Vertex() {
    pos = new Vector2(0.0, 0.0);
    color = new Vector4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    texCoord = new Vector2(0.0, 0.0);
  }

  List<double> getElements() {
    List<double> result;
    result = [pos.x, pos.y, color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a, texCoord.x, texCoord.y];

    return result;
  }
}

class QuadRenderer {

  String _vsSource = """
  precision highp float;

  attribute vec2 a_pos;
  attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
  attribute vec4 a_color;

  uniform mat4 proj;
  uniform mat4 model;

  varying vec2 v_texCoord;
  varying vec4 v_pos;
  varying vec4 v_color;

  void main() {
    v_pos = proj * model * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
    v_color = a_color;
    gl_Position = proj * model * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
  }
  """, _fsSource = """
  precision highp float;

  uniform sampler2D texture;

  varying vec2 v_texCoord;
  varying vec4 v_pos;
  varying vec4 v_color;

  void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture, v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
  }
  """;

  WebGL.Shader vs, fs;
  WebGL.Program program;
  WebGL.Buffer vab, iab;
  int posLocation;
  Matrix4 projMatrix;
  Vertex v0, v1, v2, v3;
  WebGL.UniformLocation projLocation, modelLocation;
  Texture texture;

  void renderQuad(Vector2 pos, num w, num h, num uo, num vo, bool normalize, {Vector4 color, double rotation}) {

    if (!texture.loaded) return;
    if (color == null) color = new Vector4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    if (rotation == null) rotation = 0.0;

    Matrix4 model = new Matrix4.identity();
    model.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    model.scale(w*1.0, h*1.0, 0.0);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation, false, model.storage);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projLocation, false, projMatrix.storage);

    if (normalize) {
      uo /= texture.width;
      vo /= texture.height;
    }

    v0.color = v1.color = v2.color = v3.color = color;
    v0.texCoord = new Vector2(uo + w * 1.0, vo + h * 1.0); v1.texCoord = new Vector2(uo + w * 1.0, vo * 1.0);
    v2.texCoord = new Vector2(uo * 1.0, vo * 1.0); v3.texCoord = new Vector2(uo * 1.0, vo + h * 1.0);

    _compileVertices();
    gl.drawElements(WebGL.TRIANGLES, 6, WebGL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  }

  void bindTexture(Texture tex) {
    texture = tex;
    gl.bindTexture(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D, texture.data);
  }

  void _compileVertices() {

    List<Vertex> vertices = [v0, v1, v2, v3];
    Float32List vertexBuffer = new Float32List(vertices.length * Vertex.elementCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      Vertex vertex = vertices[i];
      vertexBuffer.setAll(i * Vertex.elementCount, vertex.getElements());
    }

    gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vab);
    gl.bufferData(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, WebGL.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, Vertex.posElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false, Vertex.stride, Vertex.posByteOffset);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, Vertex.colorElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false, Vertex.stride, Vertex.colorByteOffset);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, Vertex.textureElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false, Vertex.stride, Vertex.textureByteOffset);
  }

  QuadRenderer() {

    vs = gl.createShader(WebGL.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, _vsSource);
    gl.compileShader(vs);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, WebGL.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs);
    }

    fs = gl.createShader(WebGL.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, _fsSource);
    gl.compileShader(fs);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, WebGL.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs);
    }

    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, WebGL.LINK_STATUS)) {
      throw gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
    }

    projLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "proj");
    modelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "model");

    gl.useProgram(program);

    v0 = new Vertex(); v1 = new Vertex(); v2 = new Vertex(); v3 = new Vertex();
    v0.pos = new Vector2(0.5, 0.5); v1.pos = new Vector2(0.5, -0.5); 
    v2.pos = new Vector2(-0.5, -0.5); v3.pos = new Vector2(-0.5, 0.5);

    gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 0, "a_pos");
    gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 1, "a_color");
    gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 2, "a_texCoord");

    List<Vertex> vertices = [v0, v1, v2, v3];
    Float32List vertexBuffer = new Float32List(vertices.length * Vertex.elementCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      Vertex vertex = vertices[i];
      vertexBuffer.setAll(i * Vertex.elementCount, vertex.getElements());
    }

    vab = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vab);
    gl.bufferData(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, WebGL.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, Vertex.posElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false, Vertex.stride, Vertex.posByteOffset);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, Vertex.colorElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false, Vertex.stride, Vertex.colorByteOffset);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, Vertex.textureElementCount, WebGL.FLOAT, false,   Vertex.stride, Vertex.textureByteOffset);

    Int16List indexBuffer = new Int16List(6);
    indexBuffer.setAll(0, [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]);

    iab = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iab);
    gl.bufferData(WebGL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, WebGL.STATIC_DRAW);
  }
}
```

The problem was that the render call renderGame() doesn't work. I know that WebGL work, cause the clear color works fine. I do not know what the problem is, so any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your question contains a lot of code. Is it possible to reduce the code to a smaller example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Just removing the `main()` method wasn't what I had in mind. This makes it even harder to reproduce your problem. You should try to find a minimal working example that allows to reproduce your problem. The harder it is for anybody to reproduce your problem the less likely it is that someone will take a stab on your problem.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to shorten it down, I'm still learning WebGL, and this is following an example, but it doesn't work. Literally, the only thing the program does is try to render to webgl from a texture, and nothing else, so I think it already is quite minimalistic.

Comment: Then it's fine. I don't know WebGL and assess if this is necessary. I just tried to make you aware that your chances for getting support can be improved by simplifying the question. If this is not feasible just ignore my comment. Please add your `main()` then.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you should use `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime`'s `millisecondsSinceEpoch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a rendering library or game engine like [Pixi Dart](https://github.com/FedeOmoto/pixi) or [StageXL](https://github.com/bp74/StageXL) instead of plain WebGL?
Those two libraries also abstract the renderer backend (use WebGL whenever possible and use canvas as a fallback).

Hope that helps if you're thinking on developing a game :)

Comment: I checked out pixi dart and I really like it! Thank you!